# How to understand dynamic range of op amp from TI's book

Tags: amplifier, low-power, output

I am reading TI's op amps for everyone.

I am very confused about its description about dynamic range as follows

[image]

I have some questions about it,

1. Since it is the maximum output voltage the op amp can achieve and the minimum output voltage the op amp can achieve, why should it be as follows: $$V_{OH(MIN)}$$ $$V_{OL(MAX)}$$
2. What does 'the most positive power supply voltage' mean in this text?
3. Actually, I have no idea what dynamic range is according to this material which should be authoritative. Can anybody give me more intuitive view of relationships between dynamic range and power supply?

Thank you!

Comment: Dynamic range defined in your text is Vout(max), that is the voltage range that the op amp can output. The op amp is powered by two voltages Vin(max), and Vin(min). The op amp output range might not be as big as the voltage powering the op amp. The highest voltage, Voh(min), is the voltage the op amp is *'guaranteed'* (by specification) to reach, and Vol(max) the lowest voltage it is  *'guaranteed'* (by specification) to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an op amp power with dual 15 volt supplies. Furthermore, let's say that the most positive voltage the op amp can put out is in the range of 12 to 14 volts. Also, let's say that the most negative it can put out is -12 to -14 volts. The VOH(min) is 12, and VOL(max) is -12. That is, the minimum high voltage is +12, and the maximum low voltage is -12. Then the dynamic range is 12 - (-12), or 24 volts.

Dynamic range is always less than the difference between the two power supplies, but it varies with op amp and power supply voltages. The same op amp mentioned above might, for instance, be able with +/- 5volt supplies to put out 1 to 4 volts (positive) and -1 to -4 volts (negative) Then its dynamic range would only be 2 volts with +/- 5 volt supplies.

Note that dynamic range, by this definition, is a worst-case number. It tells you what the guaranteed output voltage swing is, not what you might get if you're lucky. The first opamp is guaranteed to output a 24 volt swing, but it might in some cases put out 28 volts.

Comment: Dynamic range would  be 8 volts with +/- 5 volt supplies, as per your assumption.

Comment: @Electroholic - Nope. VOHmin is 1, VOLmax is -1. 1 volt to -1 volt is 2 volts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complementary answer to WhatRoughBeast. Sometimes pictures are worth a great deal.

It is important to note that the output voltage an amplifier can achieve is often asymmetric; the output can swing closer to one power rail than the other.

Beyond that, the output swing relative to the power rail can vary with the power supply provided.

Take [this amplifier](http://www.linear.com/product/LT6020) as an example.

From the [datasheet](http://www.linear.com/docs/44346) we can extract the necessary information.

On a +/-15V supply, we get the following results:

[image: LT6020 Voh and Vol at 30V supply]

Note the test conditions - with a lower load resistance, we will not achieve these outputs. In this case, our maximum dynamic swing across all temperatures is 30V - 490mV = 29.51V, but our maximum symmetric swing is 29.4V (because the negative swing cannot go closer to the -15V supply than 300mV)

At a total of 3V supply, though, we get:

[image: LT6020 swing with Vs = 3V]

At this total supply we have an output dynamic swing of 3V - 250mV = 2.75V, but a symmetric swing of 2.7V. The difference can be explained because the same load gives a different output *current* requirement, which is lower at 3V, so the output can swing slightly closer to the power rails.

Alluding to the variation based on load:

[image: Vout vs. Iout positive]

Note that at maximum temperature, an output of just under 5mA means the output can swing no closer than to within 1V of the positive power rail, quite a bit different to the datasheet parameter (but that is still true as the load is specified).

Looking at the other side:

[image: Vout vs. Iout negative]

The output swing goes a bit (not much) closer to the power rail at the same output current.

This is listed as a *rail to rail* output device, but it is clear that at moderate loads, it is not. With a 5mA load on +/-15V power supplies, the dynamic swing capability is something less than 28V, typical.

When calculating the dynamic swing of the output of an amplifier, the load is critical (and the datasheet should always list the load applied for the parameter), and it will also vary with temperature. Check the graphs as well as the parameter in the Electrical Characteristics table(s).

Note that the graphs here are apparently normalised to the *typical* value found in the characteristics table.